# What is the meaning of this phrase? (to organize relief at such short notice)

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> It is next to impossible **to organize relief at such short notice**. We
> need some more time to make it work

At first I thought that I can't quite right understand the word usage (it was a task to insert the right word, "notice"), but then it occurred to me that maybe I'm missing the general meaning.

I looked up http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ and found only these definitions of the most confusing word:

> NOTICE:
>
> 1. The act of noting or observing; perception or attention: That detail escaped my notice.
> 2. Respectful attention or consideration: grateful for the teacher's notice.
> 3. A written or printed announcement: a notice of sale.
> 4. a. A formal announcement, notification, or warning, especially an announcement of one's intention to withdraw from an agreement or leave
>    a job: gave my employer two weeks' notice; raised the price without
>    notice. b. The condition of being formally warned or notified: put us
>    on notice for chronic lateness.
> 5. A printed critical review, as of a play or book.

but none of them fit in right, as I think

Comment: Sometimes it helps if we try to search for a string of words, instead of just a word. For example, here is a definition of **[at/on short notice](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/at-on-short-notice)**: without being given much warning before something happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is sense 4. But instead of giving a notice well in advance, like the example of giving your employer two week's notice, whoever is asking for relief did not give enough time. "Short notice" means insufficient notice.